# How does Bing know the terms that I had recently Googled in the past month?

Tags: google, bing

After I typed "a" into Bing, a list of terms that I had recently queried in Google appeared in purple.

[image]

How does Bing know what terms I recently Googled?

Comment: I can't reproduce. I'm curious what browser you are using.

Comment: Google Chrome on Mac Lion... Hey, you're right. I can't reproduce this effect in Firefox, Opera, or Safari. Weird.

Comment: Ah, the purple list of Googled terms in Bing disappeared after I cleared my autofill options in Chrome. Interestingly, just clearing cache and cookies did not remove the list.

Comment: That seems to be possibly a usage of local storage on browsers or cookies from where they could fetch recently searched terms.

Comment: This is also because the form field `<name>` is `q` just like Google's. Doesn't look like they are taking advantage of local storage, just taking advantage of all the browsers autofill options on form field values of same name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Dez has pointed out, it is due to the [Autofill](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142893)/[AutoComplete](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/fill-in-website-forms-and-passwords-automatically) feature that [browsers (not just Chrome; although it may not be activated by default) implement to make filling forms easy](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2007/03/leveraging-textbox-autocomplete-feature.html).